# after renaming the page everything works fine.

Tags: asp.net, .net, gridview, rendering, aspxgridview

we are facing a strange issue. we have a (custom)file upload control in our page . which binds files to a grid view. say our page name is xxx.aspx. our custom file upload control works fine every where except xxx.aspx. when we attach files on xxx.aspx it does not show files in grid although grid view contains the attached file in it(on server side) but is not rendering on client side. (its out side of an update panel, so its not an ajax problem). 
if we rename the page to something else, say "aaa.aspx", it starts working fine.

so there is something with the xxx.aspx.

what it could be ? any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try checking your header on aspx and class on server side
cause when you just rename your asp page the code doesnt change itself so you have to rename also
like this

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPage.master" AutoEventWireup="false"
CodeFile="xxx.aspx.vb" Inherits="xxx" Title="Untitled Page" %>
```

and on your server side

```
Partial Class xxx
end class
```

get my point?